# Exclude a file from package by Webpack

Tags: webpack, grafana

I participate in the development of a JS web app - a [Grafana plugin](https://grafana.com/docs/plugins/developing/development/) which is packed for production using `Webpack`.

Currently all the scripts within the `src` folder are joined in a single file `module.js` and saved in another folder called `dist`.

Is it possible that I instruct `Webpack` to exclude a single file - `config.js` from that bundle, but keeping the file part of the app - be able to `import config from './config'`. I know how to copy that file along some other resources to the `dist` folder using the `CopyWebpackPlugin` plugin.

Because it is a plugin - part of a bigger application, there is no way that we include additional `<script>` tags in the HTML (at least not the proper way in the `<head>` or the end of the `<body>` of the HTML).

The idea is that we can easily change the content in the config file without having to pack it all over again and again.

I don't mind if the file I use for configuration is in `.ts`, `.js`, or `.json` format

I found a similar [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41348836/exclude-ts-js-file-from-bundle-using-webpack) but it is for Angular and with no definite solution unfortunately.

Thanks to all the readers!

Comment: What do you mean by "keeping the file part of the app". Which type of app are you developing (node, web)? When you want to bundle a web app and still keep the config file separate from the rest of the bundle, then you would have to include it in a script tag in the html. Or you would have to bundle again, if you `require` it. Not sure, if I have understood your idea fully, some more infos would be helpful.

Comment: @ford04 - I precised the question as you requested. If you need more info I will be happy to provide. Thanks for the assistance!